# How do I get the outgoing JSON from a CloudKit request?

Tags: c#, ios, json, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

I'm debugging the JSON for a C# app that POSTs to CloudKit using server keys.

According to the docs, the JSON I need to use to [create/modify](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitWebServicesReference/ModifyRecords/ModifyRecords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH2-SW9) a record looks like this:

```
{
    "operationType" : "create",
    "record" : {
        "recordType" : "Artist",
        "fields" : {
            "firstName" : {"value" : "Mei"},
            "lastName" : {"value" : "Chen"}
        }
        "recordName" : "Mei Chen"
    },
}
```

When I go to [JSON2Csharp](http://json2csharp.com/), I get the error below. I need to determine if the documentation is invalid, or if the server actually wants this JSON as-is.

[image]

**Question**

How can I obtain the JSON used in the apple CloudKit framework when it's sent to the CK server?

Comment: (note, wrong screenshot, but the error is the same)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON doesn't appear to be formatted properly.

Please see if this fits your needs, as I believe it to be correctly formatted and structured to what you are working with:

```
{
    "operationType" : "create",
    "record" : 
    {
        "recordType" : "Artist",
        "fields" : 
        {
            "firstName" : {"value" : "Mei"},
            "lastName" : {"value" : "Chen"}
        },
        "recordName" : "Mei Chen"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot.  The JSON is straight from Apple's documentation. My goal is to figure out what is the right format the servers are expecting.

Comment: The example from their documentation may simply be wrong.  You definitely need a `,` before the `recordName`, as that's part of the `record` group.  You do NOT need a `,` between the final two brackets, as there are no additional fields mentioned.